# phonegap ios keyboard with numbers only for number field on iPad

Tags: ios, objective-c, html, cordova, html-input

I have an issue with a number field. Problem is: nothing but numbers is allowed, so i want the keyboard coming up when i click it to be the 'tel'-type, with only numbers. Doesn't seem to be possible through cordova/phonegap though and i haven't written a line of ObjC code.

I know i can restrict the app client side through JS/jQuery to not take anything but numbers, but thats not the way i wanna go around it if i can help it.

so in short terms: How can i get the phone-keyboard to show itself when i click an input?

Hope anyone can help.

Comment: try this <input type="number" />

Comment: also this one <input type="text" pattern="[0-9]*">

Comment: thx for replying, but tried both and they dont invoke the numbers ONLY keyboard, but the numbers and symbols

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <input type="number" name="someid" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)
```

now open number key board only but user change to string mode. use this code and control numbers only allowed

```
function isNumberKey(evt){
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode
    if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: This doesnt invoke the right keyboard, but just restrict user input, which i dont wanna use if possible

Comment: Actually what i ended up using was this. It's not the final solution, but since there is no keyboard on iPad for numbers ONLY i had to go with this and design my own virtual keyboard when i get that far. Thanks for the input everyone.

Answer (score 4):

Use pattern attribute in input tag;

```
<input type="number" pattern="\d*" />
```

This will popup the default numeric keyboard.

Comment: I don't want the keyboard with all the symbols. numbers Only. And this one opens the one i don't want.